# Given type T, resolve and use other object of generic type Calc<T> to process T

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

Sorry if the title doesn't explain the question very well, but I couldn't think any better name. This might end up being a quite long question, but please bear with me.

Let's say I have two types of vehicles `Car` and `Yacht` which extend an interface called `IVehicle`.

The interface itself doesn't matter much for this question, but the classes contain properties describing them.

I then have a `ITaxCalculator<T> where T : IVehicle` which contains method `double Calculate(T vehicle);`.

There are then several classes which implement different versions of `ITaxCalculator<T>` (and take different constructor arguments), such as:

- `LegitYachtTaxCalculator : ITaxCalculator<Yacht>`
- `TaxHavenYachtTaxCalculator : ITaxCalculator<Yacht>`
- `CarTaxCalculator : ITaxCalculator<Car>`

I then have a `List<IVehicle>` containing my multiple cars and yachts, and I want to calculate the total amount of taxes I'm going to have to pay for them while at the same time being able to switch out the method used to calculate each type's taxes.

---

Here's some code:

### Interfaces:

#### `ITaxCalculator<T>`

```
public interface ITaxCalculator<T> where T : IVehicle
{
    double Calculate(T vehicle);
}
```

#### `IVehicle`

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    string RegistrationPlate { get; }
}
```

### Implementations

#### `Car`

```
public class Car : IVehicle
{
    public Car(string registrationPlate)
    {
        RegistrationPlate = registrationPlate;
    }
    public string RegistrationPlate { get; }
}
```

#### `Yacht`

```
public class Yacht : IVehicle
{
    public int WeightInTons { get; }
    public Yacht(string registrationPlate, int weightInTons)
    {
        RegistrationPlate = registrationPlate;
        WeightInTons = weightInTons;
    }
    public string RegistrationPlate { get; }
}
```

#### `CarTaxCalculator : ITaxCalculator<Car>`

```
public class CarTaxCalculator : ITaxCalculator<Car>
{
    public double Calculate(Car vehicle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Calculating tax for {vehicle.GetType().FullName} with plate {vehicle.RegistrationPlate} using {this.GetType().FullName}");

        return 4999.95;
    }
}
```

#### `LegitYachtTaxCalculator : ITaxCalculator<Yacht>`

```
public class LegitYachtTaxCalculator : ITaxCalculator<Yacht>
{
    public double WeightMultiplier { get; }
    public LegitYachtTaxCalculator(double weightMultiplier)
    {
        WeightMultiplier = weightMultiplier;
    }
    public double Calculate(Yacht vehicle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Calculating tax for {vehicle.GetType().FullName} with plate {vehicle.RegistrationPlate} using {this.GetType().FullName}");

        return vehicle.WeightInTons * WeightMultiplier;
    }
}
```

#### `TaxHavenYachtTaxCalculator : ITaxCalculator<Yacht>`

```
public class TaxHavenYachtTaxCalculator : ITaxCalculator<Yacht>
{
    public double Calculate(Yacht vehicle)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Calculating tax for {vehicle.GetType().FullName} with plate {vehicle.RegistrationPlate} using {this.GetType().FullName}");

        return 0.0; // No taxes, woho!
    }
}
```

### Main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<IVehicle> vehicles = new List<IVehicle>
    {
        new Car("PLT111"),
        new Yacht("PLT333", 2500)
    };

    double totalTaxes = 0;

    foreach (var vehicle in vehicles)
    {
        //Here I want to use engines which are configurable earlier to calculate the taxes for the vehicles
    }
}
```

---

I've tried to solve this in many ways such as

- IoC containers
- A much lighter "Resolver" variant where you register engines in a class containing a `Dictionary<Type, object>` where `object` is ITaxCalculators registered and resolved through methods such as

  1. `public ITaxCalculator<T> GetTaxCalculator<T>() where T : IVehicle`
  2. `public void RegisterTaxCalculator<T>(ITaxCalculator<T> calculator) where T : IPosition`
- Passing the ITaxCalculator to every instance of T during its creation, and letting T calculate its own taxes by using it.

They all end up feeling overly complex, using bad practices or requiring too much boilerplate. So I'm wondering what the best way would be to structure this? Am I on the wrong track from the start, or is there any pattern I haven't thought about yet?

Thanks!

Comment: What was wrong with IoC containers? How flexible configuration should be? Who will configure tax calculators? When they must be configured?

Comment: The TaxCalculators will be predefined in the library, but the user of the library should be able to insert them into "slots" and then ask the library to calculate the total taxes for a list of different IVehicle implementations using earlier configured slots. The problem with IoC approach was that it ended up being more of a service discoverer when used from within the loop, and it also required some not-so-nice casting and other magic tricks.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm following the "slots" part. Is it possible that instead of returning a tax amount that you want to return a tax object which contains both the definition of the tax and the amount? Then instead of just getting a bunch of amounts or a sum you've got a list of different taxes with amounts.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need a way to define mapping between tax calculator and vehicle.

First of all, make tax calculator non-generic:

```
public interface ITaxCalculator
{
    double Calculate(IVehicle vehicle);
}
```

It's much easier to discover all non-generic implementations, load them in collection, and call `Calculate`.

To deal with particular `IVehicle` implementation details, declare base class for tax calculators, and make *it* generic:

```
public abstract class TaxCalculator<T> : ITaxCalculator
    where T : IVehicle
{
    public double Calculate(IVehicle vehicle)
    {
        // this is a single place, where cast is required
        return Calculate((T)vehicle);
    }

    protected abstract double Calculate(T vehicle);
}
```

Mapping task leads us to metadata.
Most of DI-containers have this feature. E.g., here are [Autofac](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html) docs.

Define the metadata class:

```
// This is metadata class;
// It defines vehicle type to calculate the tax value
public class TaxCalculatorMetadata
{
    public Type VehicleType { get; set; }
}
```

Register `ITaxCalculator` implementations:

```
// Every implementation of ITaxCalculator must be registered like this
builder.RegisterType<CarTaxCalculator>()
    .As<ITaxCalculator>()
    .WithMetadata<TaxCalculatorMetadata>(m => m.For(_ => _.VehicleType, typeof(Car)));
```

Now you can load all `ITaxCalculator` implementations, filter them somehow ("insert them into "slots""), and get particular calculator using vehicle type from "slot":

```
var vehicles = new List<Vehicle>
{
    // ...
};

// assuming, that tax calculators were imported  
// using IEnumerable<Lazy<ITaxCalculator, TaxCalculatorMetadata>>
foreach (var vehicle in vehicles)
{
    var taxCalculator = taxCalculators
        .First(_ => _.Metadata.VehicleType == vehicle.GetType());

    Console.WriteLine(taxCalculator.Value.Calculate(vehicle));
}
```